# Using .Net to capture rendered HTML from URL

Tags: .net, html, rendering, innerhtml

Is it possible to use a technique to redirect to a URL from within an application and simply take the page content that would be displayed but instead render it to email or otherwise?  I believe I've seen the use of InnerHTML but is this really the best way?  It seems a bit of a hack, to me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Download the page using a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), put it into the `Body` of a [`MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) (also check out the `IsBodyHtml` and `AlternateViews` properties), and `Send` it using an [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).

However, the page at the URL should be created so it has a good chance to be consumed by e-mail clients: very small amount of CSS, table-based layout (argh...), good look even when images are not rendered by the client, left-aligned text, no Javascript, no Flash, no Silverlight, no embedded videos, etc. See [this](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/email-marketing-field-guide/) and [this](http://www.email-standards.org/) for the details of HTML e-mail creation.

If the page you download does not obey these rules, you may have to modify it before sending. The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which was suggested by @Gaby, is an HTML parser, and one of the best tools for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `WebClient.DownloadFile` method to save the file and then do whatever you wish to do with it.